# PHP split Paypal payment into two accounts

Tags: php, paypal

Is it possible using PayPal split all incoming payments into two accounts?

Me and another guy are partnering up to sell some products, we need a way for all of our incoming payments to be split 50/50. Is this possible at all? I'd really like to use Stripe but not against using PayPal.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can check [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)

> Adaptive payments handles payments between a sender of a payment and one or more receivers of the payment. You are an application owner, such as a merchant that owns a website, the owner of a widget on a social networking site, the provider of a payment application on mobile phones, and so on. Your application is the caller of Adaptive Payments API operations.